# How to filter data by two fields in django model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Here is queryset and I want to filter by two django fields.

```
#models.py
class ExmapleModel(models.Model):
    first_field = models.IntegerFiled()
    second_field = models.IntegerField()
```

and here views

```
#views.py
class ExampleApiView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = ExmapleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExmapleModelrSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        ...
        if condition:
            return qs.filter(lambda item: item.first_field < item.second_field)
        return qs
```

I tried to filter like this, but of course it doesn't work

```
qs.filter(lambda item: item.first_field < item.second_field)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import F

qs.filter(first_field__lt=F('second_field'))
```